# XSL-FO Remove Static Content when break-before creates empty page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have added to my xml elements that they are forced to be rendered on either an even or an odd page. This I have done with the attribute `break-before="odd-page"` or also `break-before="even-page"`. So far everything works great!

My problem is that it can happen that an empty page is created, for example when an element is already on an even page and is then forced to start on an even page. The created empty page (only the body is empty) still has the same `static-content` as the page before.

But I want a completely empty page to be inserted in such a case without page number, header or similar.

Is this somehow possible?

I am using Apache-Formatting-Objects-Processor 2.3 (fop 2.3)

Answer (score 2):

You want an `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_conditional-page-master-reference) with a `blank-or-not-blank` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#blank-or-not-blank) value of `blank`.

The first `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` for which all of its traits are true is the one that is selected, so the new `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` should come before your `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` that refer to the page masters for odd and even pages.  Here's an example that comes from a FOP test file (I think):

```
<fo:page-sequence-master master-name="pages">
  <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first-page"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="last" master-reference="last-page"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" 
      master-reference="blank-page"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="odd" master-reference="odd-page"/>
    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference odd-or-even="even" master-reference="even-page"/>
  </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
</fo:page-sequence-master>
```

For completely blank pages, the second part of the solution is not direct your existing `fo:static-content` to any regions on the blank pages. The `fo:simple-page-master` for blank pages should either not contain `fo:region-after`, etc., or, if it did include them, those regions should have different `region-name` values to the `flow-name` values in your existing `fo:static-content`.

Comment: But odd or even is always true... so he will never take the `<fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" master-reference="blank-page"/>`. And its not even a first or a last page of the document. It can be any page within the `page-sequence`....

Comment: Because `odd-or-even="any"` (its default) is always true and `page-position="any"` (its default) is always true, the formatter will use `<fo:conditional-page-master-reference blank-or-not-blank="blank" master-reference="blank-page"/>` for any blank page (since that makes the `blank-or-not-blank` trait to be true, hence all three traits are true).  For a non-blank page (other than the first and last pages of the page sequence, in this case), the formatter will not choose the 'blank-page' page master.  It will fall through to considering `odd-or-even="odd"` and then `blank-or-not-blank="even"`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier. As every new page is added to the page sequence, the formatter goes through the alternatives in the `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_repeatable-page-master-alternatives) to work out which page master to use. The formatter goes through the alternatives in sequence for every new page. (You can put more than just one `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` inside an `fo:page-sequence-master`, and you can limit the number of pages that one `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives` can generate, but that's the basics.)